# 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I'm trying to close a modal with the 'x' button but I'm getting this error `'list' object has no attribute 'click'` so I looked for other answers and they said to use close_button[0].click() since find_by_element stores a list but still getting error as `IndexError: list index out of range`

I need help to close this modal

my code

```
close_button=browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="prefix-overlay-header"]/button')
close_button[0].click()
```

The element that I'm trying to access and close.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My 2c using [Expected Conditions](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) (waits):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://site.tld')

el = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Close subscription dialog"]')))
el.click()
```

---

Based on your comment, you may want to use the following code after "*click is executed*" and which opens a new tab:

```
wait.until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2)) # wait for 2 tabs (windows) to be open
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1]) # switch to newly opened tab
```

Comment: it actually happens because in the previous page when I click on a link then it opens in a new tab but control is still in the previous tab so it can't find the close button as the control is at the previous tab still

Comment: if you see in this photo, https://imgur.com/a/Zc9lInW in the 7th cell, when that click is executed, then it opens the link in a new tab but the control is still at parent window it seems and that is why, selenium can't find the close button

Comment: how do I switch back to my parent window again? @CONvid19

Comment: `driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0]) ` - https://www.techbeamers.com/switch-between-windows-selenium-python/

Answer (score 3):

It is because your a trying to find the elements by

```
browser.find_elements_by path
```

Note that you can see elements. Elements is a list.It is plural
Try this:

```
 browser.find_element_by_path
```

And then use closebutton.click()

Comment: I'm getting this error `NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="prefix-overlay-header"]/button"}` I took the xpath by going to inspect element but still it says no element found

Comment: Try using find_element by class_name or by css_selector

Comment: Could you tell me the name of the website

Comment: I added another answer, please check. It worked for me in your website

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. As there is a space you should use css selector. The important things are the points(.)

```
close_button = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.prefix-overlay-close.prefix-overlay-action-later')
close_button.click()
```

It worked for me in your given website. Please check once

Comment: actually when I click on a link on the previous tab, then it opens up this page in new tab, so it can't find the element. is there any way that I could shift control to this new tab?

Comment: why do u have 2 tabs

Comment: it opens in new tab automatically when i click on the go to data online link. can't help it

Comment: Is it not working with the code which I showed. Can u show the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212549/discussion-between-n-sivaram-and-reduxhelpplz).